# Android Jetpack Navigation does not update onNewIntent/onCreate intent extra data to the destinations

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, onnewintent

I have an activity with `NavHost` composable calling a simple composable function with a `TextField` set as start destination. There is a `ViewModel` that stores that text field text `state` in `MutableState<String>` object. This activity receives `android.intent.action.SEND` intent set in Manifest with mime type of `"text/plain"`. Now, when I share text from any other application, the text field does not receive the text, although, I can see that `onNewIntent()` callback is being fired and intent `EXTRA_TEXT` is being delivered. The view model text state is getting updated with `EXTRA_TEXT` value, however, it's not being updated in the `TextField` composable function. If I remove `NavHost`, and call the composable with `TextField` directly, the `TextField` text is updated normally- what am I missing here?

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val viewModel by viewModels<MainViewModel>()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            NavigationTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    val navController = rememberNavController()
                    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "Home") {
                        composable(route = "Home"){
                            TextShareInput()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // this gets called when I share text data from another app, 
    // intent is delivered correctly, viewmodel state is updated
    // but, the text field does not receive the new state value
    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        intent?.let { newIntent ->
            newIntent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)?.let {
                viewModel.editText.value = it
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TextShareInput(viewModel: MainViewModel = androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel()) {
    Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        TextField(
            value = viewModel.editText.value,
            onValueChange = { viewModel.editText.value = it })
    }
}


class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val editText: MutableState<String> = mutableStateOf("")
}
```

Comment: Okay, I did some research, and realized that I need to use deepLinks to receive intents in navigation component.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to pass the instance of the `viewModel` you are creating in the activity to the `TextShareInput` Composable. Your activity and viewModel  have separate instances of the `MainViewModel` .

So you have:

```
composable(route = "Home"){
  TextShareInput(viewModel)
}
```

Comment: I realized the mistake I have made in the code resulting in multiple ```viewModel``` instances, as you correctly pointed out. This has fixed the issue. Nevertheless, the recommended approach to navigate to deep links from navigation component is by using deepLinks.

Comment: Can you explain why multiple viewmodels are being created? Should not the delegate extension function return an existing viewModel if it already exists?

Comment: Some observations, there is nothing wrong with the viewmodel code, but multiple instances of viewmodel is the result of attribute ```launchMode```.